# In banach space every closed convex bounded set is a retract of a closed ball

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, nonlinear-analysis

In a Banach space (not necessarily finite-dimensional), we can find a closed ball with a sufficiently large radius that contains $A$ where $A$ is a closed, convex, and bounded set. My question is does there exist a retraction from $B$ to $A$?

If so, how do we go about constructing this mapping?

Comment: In a Hilbert space, you could use the projection onto $A$.